# Powershell command with sql config params

Tags: powershell, azure

I am creating a VM on Azure with the help of below Powershell commands

```
New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $StorageName -Location $location 
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'my Azure Account' -CurrentStorageAccount $StorageName

$vm=New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmname -InstanceSize ExtraSmall -ImageName $image |
       Add-AzureProvisioningConfig  -Windows -Password mypassword -AdminUsername username|
       Add-AzureDataDisk -CreateNew -DiskSizeInGB 50 -DiskLabel 'datadisk1' -LUN 0 |
       Add-AzureEndpoint -Protocol tcp -LocalPort 80 -PublicPort 80 -Name 'web' `
               -LBSetName 'lbweb' -ProbePort 80 -ProbeProtocol http -ProbePath '/' 

New-AzureVM -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -VMs $vm  -Location $location
```

I am using a sql server 2008 R2 VMImage for image parameter. VM is created successfully.

When I Remotely connect to this VM and open the sql server on this VM. I am not able to log on the sql server in any mode "Window" and "Server".

My problem 
(1) Can we supply SQL credential with create VM command.? so that my VM configure that in SQL server.
(2) Any other solution for the same.?

Thanks

Comment: if i understand you correctly , you want to provision different credentials, right? that's not possible with the Azure Powershell cmdlets. Have you checked the server / instance name  of your SQL config? and make sure it's correct ...?

Comment: Means we do not able to supply the sql configuration  parameter like username and password for server authentication. I had tried with the "." and instance name both but still I am not login in to sql server. Even I tried with window credential which are supplied for -Window but still the same not login.

Comment: I just tried with the Window Authentication it is working but for server authentication what i need to try.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure we can supply or cann't supply SQL config  params by Powershell but we can enable the SQL server for server authentication and we allow it for public access follow this post steps

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707550/azure-virtual-machine-with-sql-image)