# Azure Virtual Machine with SQL image

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have created a virtual machine on azure with the help of "SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Web on WS 2008 R2" VMImage, now when I remote connected to the virtual machine and open sql server try to login in server authentication mode. It is not accepting my credentials. Any one help which credentials I need to use.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long R&D my problem has been resolved by using the following steps :

1 . We need to enable SQL server for login as server authentication mode.
    [technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)

1. We need to enable it for public access

   a. Create an endpoint in virtual machine dashboard 
     [www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/)
     [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj823131.aspx#endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj823131.aspx#endpoint)

   b. Create a Firewall rule on virtual machine to allow the SQL to public access 
     follow the below link and create the inbound firewall rule for sql
       [blogs.biztalk360.com/windows-azure-virtual-machines-virtual-network-may-not-ping-automatically/](http://blogs.biztalk360.com/windows-azure-virtual-machines-virtual-network-may-not-ping-automatically/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the administrator credentials you specified when you created the VM from the gallery image. Azure grants that account sysadmin rights on the SQL Server explicitly. Once you log on to the SQL Server with that account, you can set the permissions to meet your needs.

The administrator is a local machine account - so you can use Windows authentication while logged in (or running SQL Server Management Studio) as that administrator.

Comment: I am able to login in window mode but when i tried in server authentication not able to login. I tried with the same credential which I specified for the VM but not able to login in server mode.
Thanks